# Span border not wrapping a image

Tags: css

I'm trying to wrap a image using a span, but when a border is applied in the span, the border is clipped. Why is this happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/c743yeLt/1/

```
<span id="imagem">
    <img src="http://www.greentechmedia.com/content/images/articles/google-utility.jpg"/>
</span>

span{
    border: 5px solid black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: The `span` is `inline` by default. Change it to `inline-block`/`block`. Floating the element would also work too, but the former options would be better - http://jsfiddle.net/yepj17nm/

Comment: Ok, but did you see that cursor:pointer is actually working all over the image? Should it be also clipped as like border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The span element is an inline element. So to see it interact with child elements better, give the span one of the following attributes:

```
display:inline-block (probably this)
display:block
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `div` seems to be the better option but u can use `display:inline-block`.

`inline-block` helps to wrap a particular element nicely within a particular width and height.Earlier this used to be achieved by float.

```
<span id="imagem">
  <img src="http://www.greentechmedia.com/content/images/articles/google-utility.jpg"/>
</span>

span{
  border: 5px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `span` is `inline` element, and a `div` is a `block` element. Use a `div` instead.

Try this
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c743yeLt/2/)

Comment: You can include a demo of your code in your answer.  In fact, you don't even need jsfiddle with the recent addition of stack snippets.